# how often should I replace the metal filter on a Bialetti Moka Express 6-cup?

Tags: moka

I've been using the same filter in my Moka pot for one year, and it looks fine. None of the holes are blocked. But I noticed that Bialetti sells gasket packs in threes with one filter included. That suggests that Bialetti expects (or wants?) you to replace the filter with every third gasket. Seems like overkill to me, but what do the experts say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to CoffeeSE!

You do not need to replace the filter that often, it is just metal  after all. As long as you can clean it properly and it functions normally there is no need to replace it just because you're replacing the gasket, especially when there's no visible corrosion or damage.

There are some people who use their Moka Pot very often, don't clean it properly and almost neglect it. They can go through gaskets fairly quickly, my mother used to change it every few months, but she just replaced the filter just once, and that was because she lost the original one. For those people getting [a few gaskets for a cheaper price per gasket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RY7OI0) makes sense. For others, getting [just one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002BLASH6) is fine. I have even seen a pack of 6 gaskets and one filter not long ago.

Clean your Moka Pot after every use (or at least rinse it thoroughly and clean it properly every few days) and you filter should last you quite a long time.

Comment: thanks. I use my Moka pot three times a day everyday. I clean the filter with a dish brush after every use (i.e. 3 x a day). I guess that's why the filter has lasted so long. What to do with those extra filters? Guess I will make a wind chime out of them.

Comment: Having one or two on hand in case one of them breaks, you lose one or it just starts rusting is certainly not a bad idea, especially since they don't take up that much space. Also, you can always sell them for some spare change.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with cheaper (non Bialetti) pots, I personally recommend replacing the metal filter once a year.

It has happened to me that such a filter cracked after over three years of everyday use (with frequent cleaning) and turned the entire kitchen into a mess. Therefore I have decided to err on the side of caution. It is conceivable that the Bialettis are more durable, but I am not willing to risk it.

Seller‘s [claims](https://www.amazon.de/Cucina-Modena-Espressokocher-Dichtung-Ersatz-Dichtungsringe/dp/B074ZHKY6K) suggest that there are both steel and aluminium filters being sold. I expect these differ in durability, but haven’t found data yet.